# How can I add latency to a http audio stream

Tags: linux, http, audio, streaming, mp3

I want to create a server which relays a http stream with about 1 min of latency.

In other words, I have a server A streaming audio at http://a.crappyserver.com:8000/stream.mp3. How can I create another stream at, say http://b.crappyserver.com:8080/stream.mp3, which has the same audio with about 1 min lag.

UPDATE: I can only use an arch linux server to do so

Answer (score 0):

You could put the streaming audio into a circular queue which holds a minute of data.  Just allocate storage and keep track of publish and consume index values.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I didn't get you

Comment: Also, I would like to do it in bash